# Fill char array from an advanced array position

Tags: c, byte

I'm coding two programs that communicates via sockets sendinc `char *` strings.

Sometimes, `read()` reads less bytes than it should, so I gotta loop that `read()` till all the bytes are read. But, for example, if I want to read a string of 100 bytes, and `read()` only receives 60 (40 are missing in the socket buffer), means the string has only data in it's 60 first positions. Now I'd want to loop the `read()` to read those extra 40 bytes but, how can I tell the `read()` function to store those bytes from the position 60 of the previously filled string in order not to overwrite the information before read?

```
char string[100];
ssize_t total_bytes = 100;
ssize_t bytes_read = 0;

do {
    //How can I read and store the array of chars in the variable string being string[bytes_read] the starting point in each iteration?
    bytes_read = read(socket, string/*?*/, total_bytes); 
    total_bytes -= bytes_read;
} while(total_bytes > 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an integer to the pointer (converted from the array, pointing at the first element of the array) to advance the position to start writing what is read.

```
    bytes_read = read(socket, string + (100 - total_bytes), total_bytes);
```

---

If you definitely want the start point to be `string[bytes_read]` (it will make it overwrite some data if 3 or more reads are done):

```
    bytes_read = read(socket, string + bytes_read, total_bytes);
```

or this may be easier (straight-forward):

```
    bytes_read = read(socket, &string[bytes_read], total_bytes);
```

Comment: In first case isn't it `string + (100 - bytes_read)` instead of `total_bytes`?

Comment: @user157629 No because there are `total_bytes` bytes, not `bytes_read` bytes, of buffer to be filled from the end of the buffer.